# Accidentally run command rm -R in Amazon EC2. Unable to login

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, login, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon EC2 for Magento website and WinScp to access SFTP.
Sometimes I'm using terminal in WinScp to execute command.

Today I need to delete some files so I used `rm -R /*` and forget to mention folder name.

Now i am unable to login using winscp to my server and the website is not working. I am getting this error in winscp:

```
"Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "ubuntu".
Server refused our key.

Authentication failed."
```

How can I login again and undo the massive erase?

Comment: I am fairly  certain that you didn't use `rm -R /*` but `rm -R *`, or else you would have needed to use `sudo` **and** got a warning.

Comment: When you can not login your instance is gone.

Comment: @Rinzwind or he just deleted his `~/.ssh`

Comment: Sure ... but the general idea of an instance is that you have a way of connecting to it. If that method is deleted the instance is gone. No access is the same as deleting the instance from the main console panel.

Comment: Hi, I didn't run command using 'sudo'
i run in local terminal of Winscp but not in 'putty' @guntbert

I saw there was thousand of line code executed with ending message 'permission denied'
 i am not assure that files are deleted or not...
is there any to login in amazon ec2 server again. i am in trouble it was my client's website.. :(

Comment: i executed command as
i was in directory `..\www\..\var\cache`
i started terminal 
generally terminal has access path of current directory in WinSCP
then i typed command `rm -R /*`
and press enter key.

Comment: I am not an expert of EC2, but you probably need to recreate an instance and recover from a backup --- you deleted all you had permission to write to.

Comment: what does command rm -R /* actually does in directory ?

Comment: It attempts to delete *everything* but due to the lack of permissions (and the fact you did not pass `--no-preserve-root`) it only deleted the files you have permission to delete. (This can include root owned files of you have write permission to the directory the root owned files are in, but this is fairly rare)

Comment: Thanks @TheNetZ . is it delete the files outside the directory also
in which right now the pointer was present.

Comment: Pointer? Do you mean `*`? That's called a wildcard or glob in this context. `*` matches any amount of any characters, so `/*` matches *every* file on any mounted filesystem on the machine, but you lack sufficient privileges to delete most files on a given linux machine. All you can normally delete on most machines are your own personal files.

Answer (score 2):

You can recover the instance data by deploying your SSH key to a new copy of the instance, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260739/add-keypair-to-existing-ec2-instance

Comment: Dude you are great. You just saved me.
I have recovered my database using this method.

attaching the link for the newbies and going to suffer in future 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934745/restore-the-mysql-database-from-frm-files

yeah but unable to recover my websites files. Files are deleted.. :( few one are left